# trace a transmission line for a certain distance

Tags: qgis, linear-referencing

I’m looking for a way to easily trace a transmission line for a certain distance.
 Here is the scenario that I am working with. We have an issue with our transmission line; our OMS tells us that there is a problem “X” number of miles from substation “Y”.
I want to be able to start from that substation and trace that transmission line upstream for the number of miles indicated to the location of the issue so we can dispatch a crew to that location.

I was hoping that someone had something that worked similar to the “Utility Network Analyst” tool.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here a couple of options:

- Use python or C++, and use the [interpolate()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a8c3bb1b01d941219f2321e6c6c3db7e1) method

  ```
  point = transmission_line_geom.interpolate(certain_distance)
  ```
- Use the [QChainage plugin](https://github.com/mach0/qchainage), treating your distance as a trivial 1-point chainage

Comment: I would prefer the qchainage plugin, but the points are always calculated from the start point of the feature. The other direction, or from somewhere in the middle is not possible. Units are always those of the layer.